# Error when passing quotes to webservice by AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I'm passing data using .ajax and here are my data and contentType attributes:

```
data: '{ "UserInput" : "' + $('#txtInput').val() + '","Options" : { "Foo1":' + bar1 + ', "Foo2":' + Bar2 + ', "Flags":"' + flags + '", "Immunity":' + immunity + '}}',
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

Server side my code looks like this:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function ParseData(ByVal UserInput As String, ByVal Options As Options) As String
```

The userinput is obvious but the `Options` structure is like the following:

```
Public Structure Options
    Dim Foo1 As Boolean
    Dim Foo2 As Boolean
    Dim Flags As String
    Dim Immunity As Integer
End Structure
```

Everything works fine when `$('#txtInput')` contains no double-quotes but if they are present I get an error (for an input of asd"):

```
{"Message":"Invalid object passed in, \u0027:\u0027 or \u0027}\u0027 expected. (22): { \"UserInput\" : \"asd\"\",\"Options\" : { \"Foo1\":false, \"Foo2\":false, \"Flags\":\"\", \"Immunity\":0}}","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeDictionary(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"}
```

Any idea how I can avoid this error? Also, when I pass the same input with quotes directly it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried escaping the text, or replacing a double-quote with a single quote, or replace the double-quote with the escape char: \"

Comment: jQuery should already be escaping the text as it's passed by `$('#txtInput').val()`. If a single quote is entered it works fine and same if the characters are escaped manually. However, if you take a look at what's actually being passed, it looks like it's already escaped: \"asd\"\" (for input of asd").

Comment: Oh yes, OK I see that now.  Sorry about that.  Have you tried the client-side Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize method to do the form serialization?  It seems like the server-side JSSerializer doesn't like something provided... and it could be that JQuery is doing something different.

Comment: I haven't and I'm ashamed to say that I've taken the easy way out: `.replace(/\"/g,"'")`. If I do find a solution I'll be sure to update.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify the last answer ... The object is going to be evaluated server-side and as the field value is a string any double quotes within it need to be escaped - so should be \".  Since this is also the js escape you need to escape both characters to \\"

```
$("#txtInput").val().replace(/\"\g, "\\\"")
```

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem.and this is my solution:

```js
$.RFStringify = function(obj) {
  var result = obj;
  try {
    result = JSON.stringify(obj);
    result = result.replace(/([^\\])\\\"/g, '$1\\\\\\\"').replace(/([^\\])\"/g, '$1\\\"').replace(/(\")\"/g, '$1\\\"');
  } catch (ex) {
    // $.RFAlertEx(ex);
  } finally {
    return result;
  }
};
var a = {
  a: 'a',
  b: {
    b: 'B',
    c: '{"c":"c","d":{"d":"D","e":"E"}}'
  }
};
$('#result').html($.RFStringify(a));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">ERROR</div>
```

wish it will be helpful.

OR

we can use `escape(result)` in the javascript client side.
And use `Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.unescape(data)` on the server side